# Auto increment column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1075

I want to make an AUTO_INCREMENT column in a database table,here is the syntax i write:

```
create table comments
(
     name varchar(20),
     mail varchar(30),
     comment varchar(100),
     com_no int auto_increment
);
```

and i get the following error:

> ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

then i made it as a primary key:

```
create table comments
(
    name varchar(20),
    mail varchar(30),
    comment varchar(100),
    com_no int primary_key auto_increment
);
```

and i get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'primary_key auto_increment,name varchar(20),mail varchar(30),comment varchar(100' at line 1

what is wrong???

Comment: When you're asking a question that's specific to MySQL (since most other SQL RDBMS don't use AUTO_INCREMENT) then you should tag your question with the mysql tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `PRIMARY KEY` without the underscore.

```
create table comments
(
    name varchar(20),
    mail varchar(30),
    comment varchar(100),
    com_no int primary key auto_increment
);
```

or

```
create table comments
(
    name varchar(20),
    mail varchar(30),
    comment varchar(100),
    com_no int auto_increment,
    primary key(`com_no`)
);
```

Comment: int unsigned would probably be better

Answer (score 2):

```
 create table comments(
    name varchar(20), 
    mail varchar(30),
    comment varchar(100),
    com_no int auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY (com_no)
  );
```

(as per on-line MySQL manual).

Comment: Yes, but yours is more refined with the opening paren on its own line.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table comments
(
    name varchar(20),
    mail varchar(30),
    comment varchar(100),
    com_no int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (com_no)
);
```

[ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use `primary key` in place of `primary_key`

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax goes like this for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `admin` (
    `id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userid` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pwd` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: id int unsigned auto_increment primary key is perfectly valid. not sure why you've specified a display width of 5, why bother with one at all in this instance ?

Answer (score 1):

In [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), there can be only one [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) column (that is generally known as [identity column](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column)) and it should be also defined as a [unique key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key). For example:

```
create table comments
(
  com_no int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(20),
  mail varchar(30),
  comment varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (com_no)
);
```

Please see [MySQL auto increment documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for more details.